# Push notification as first interaction with Facebook Messenger Bot?

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

Does anyone know if you can bypass the "get started" button through facebook messenger for a user to engage with a chatbot? I was thinking about linking from a webpage, and when someone clicks the button the bot would automatically push a message. Is this possible? Most of the documentation I see says the user has to press the "Get Started" before the bot can send messages.

Can I do this through the checkbox plugin to then push a message from a chatbot?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set a welcome screen for your Messenger app, but it's highly recommended.

Linking from a normal button on your website won't work, since the person has to actually interact with your app (send a message, tap a button, etc.) before your webhook gets notified. One option is to use the 'Send to Messenger' button plugin on your site. This goes through a FB login step, so it opts-in the person and sends a message_optins event to your webhook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/send-to-messenger-plugin